Rules on Feats When Creating Custom Backgrounds with Player's Handbook (2024)
In the 5e Player's Handbook (first printed in 2014), the text provides the option of "Customizing a Background" on page 125 but makes no reference to Feats.
The D&D Adventurer's League Player's Guide, version 14 (with an effective date of March 4, 2024) states with reference to Backgrounds:

"You can create a custom background or use any available background as
presented. If you choose a background that does not grant a feat, you
may choose one of the following feats for your character: Skilled or
Tough."

In the updated Player's Handbook (2024) in Chapter 2 "Creating a Character" under the section entitled "Backgrounds and Species from Older Books", it states

"if the background you choose doesn’t provide a feat, you gain an
Origin feat of your choice."

So my question is: if I want to create a custom background which complies with current Adventurer's League rules, and in consideration that the Player's Handbook (2024) has been released six months after the Season 14 AL Guide and is therefore more recent, am I able to add an Origin feat of my choice to a custom background, or am I still limited to either Skilled or Tough?

You can choose any origin feat, as AL now uses the 2024 rules
Yesterday this article was released on D&D Beyond, stating that the AL will use the 2024 rules as soon as they are available. The 2024 PHB is officially being released today, so AL will use these rules effective today. As you clearly quoted, the 2024 rules allow you to choose any origin feat if your background does not provide any and as these are now the official rules being used by the AL, you can indeed choose any origin feat you want.
